# Custom template route is not working for Get methods without Ids. Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

The APIs call to a testdata controller is only working for REST calls with Ids.
I have a custom routing showed bellow and every time I call  `http://localhost:56762/api/web/testdata/` nothing happens(I set a breakpoint on `IEnumerable<TestData> Get()`, and it is not called). Howver, if I call `http://localhost:56762/api/web/testdata/1` I have the get method with Id working.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "TestData",
routeTemplate: "api/web/testdata/{id}",
defaults: new {controller="testdata", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

// GET api/web/testdata/5
public string Get(int id)
{
return "TEST DATA!";
}

public IEnumerable<TestData>  Get()
{
   ...

  return listTestData;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a bracket for `testdata` in `routeTemplate`, see below:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "TestData",
        routeTemplate: "api/web/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Update

If you want to specify a specific controller for your route, see below:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "TestData",
            routeTemplate: "api/web/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "testdata", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

**Note**: You need to delete or comment out the Default Api route in the Register method.

Comment: Thank you Lin. I added the bracket but it didn't work.

Comment: thank you this could work but this not not what I am seeking. I want to be able to specify a specific controller for a specific route.

Comment: Thank you Lin but still with {controller} it is not working :( it only work when I add the id.

Comment: hi @Devsined, I guess the problem is you left the Default Api route in the Register method, You should delete it and use my updated part of the answer.

Comment: Thank you. You were right I delete the Default Api route and it works properly